# Can not get kibana logs

Tags: logging, kibana, kibana-4

I am unable to get kibana logs.

**/var/log/kibana/kibana.stdout** as well as **kibana.stderr**
seem to have no logs being written to them (I am getting undefined errors in my Kibana)

In the kibana.yml file, I have then also set

```
logging.dest: /var/logs/kibana.log
```

while inserting a kibana.log file into this directory... but again nothing is being written to the file.

How do I obtain the Kibana logs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: had you made a typo? 
`/var/log/kibana/kibana.stdout`  while `/var/logs/kibana.log`

Comment: another reason might be permission issue on your log path, make sure current user get the write permission to the log file